# Matlab function parameter includes h. I want plot title to include same h. How to do?

Tags: matlab, plot, title, figure

function parameter includes h(=10). I want plot title to include the same h. how to do?

```
function G=graphit(X,Y,ye,h)
plot(X,Y,'-'); 
grid
title([ 'Approximate and Exact Solution @h= .', num2str(h)])
```

Thanks.
MM

Comment: Why doesn't your code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` to create a formatted string

```
title( sprintf( 'Approximate and Exact Solution. h = %.0f', h ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
title(['Approximate and Exact Solution ',num2str(h),' .'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
title_string = sprintf('Approximate and Exact Solution @h= %d.',h) % change d to f for floats
title(title_string)
```

I'd use a proper string-formatting tool such as [`sprintf`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) for building correctly formatted titles.

Answer (score 0):

Despite 3 excellent answers given in less than 5 minutes, none of the suggested code would run properly. Basically, I got almost identical results as when I ran my original code.

It turns out that leading zeroes in a number for h such as 01 or 05 will cause the system to drop the zero. This was a problem for me since I wanted h values to be as they are .05, .025, .01. Further, the Matlab software seemed to become confused with a specified decimal point followed by a number with leading zeroes. The way around this was to pass the decimal point with the h value (.10,.05,.025,.01). See code below.

Input is

```
X,Y,xe,ye,.01
```

Working code:

```
function G=graphit(X,Y,xe,ye,h)
hold on; 
plot(X,Y,'-'); plot(X,ye,'-.'); 
hold off
title([ 'Approximate and Exact Solution @h=', num2str(h)])
```

Expected and attained output:
    Approximate and Exact Solution @h=0.01

Voila! Thanks for those replies...

Comment: So you wanted to print "0.01" but was passing the value 10 instead? That makes no sense...

Comment: This shows why it's so important to include a [mcve] in your question - this answer does not describe the same problem stated in the question.

Comment: I was trying to save keystrokes when I entered h  i.e 10 rather than .10.  I will include minimal complete and verifiable example next time. Thank you for the suggestion. I have been trying to do minimal complete.